# Flask flash not appearing on deployment

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, pythonanywhere

```
@app.route("/communicate", methods = ["POST"])
def communicate():
  data = request.get_json()
  for i in data:
    flash(i)
    
  print(data)
  return "Hello"
```

I have this /communicate link that gets the json data from an event listener with

```
if (messages.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let data = JSON.stringify(messages)
    
    fetch(`${window.origin}/communicate`, {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "include",
    body: JSON.stringify(messages),
    cache: "no-cache",
    headers: new Headers({
      "content-type": "application/json"
    })
  })
    location.reload()
  }
```

When I'm testing the exact same code on my local the flash inside the for loop is working. However, when I deployed it on heroku and pythonanywhere it stopped working.

Note: The /communicate route on deployment still gets the data from the js perfectly fine, it's just the flashing of every content of data that is bugging.

I tried these methods:

- Removing location.reload()
- Changing the get_flashed_messages() to a specific html file instead of being on base.html

Side note: I used location.reload() to refresh the page and load/update the flashed messages.

Thanks~

Comment: I also tried to look closely on the access.log / server.log of pythonanywhere and it matches the same log I'm seeing when I'm doing it on my local environment.

Comment: Did you check the developer panel in the browser (F12)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an access to any computers as of now as I only code on my mobile phone, but I tried some application that showed me the get/post requests and the local and deploy matched.    Local (when button is pressed) 127.0.0.1 - - "POST /communicate HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - "GET /static/form-valid.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -, Deployed (when button is pressed): https://winmarimanzano.pythonanywhere.com/communicate

https://winmarimanzano.pythonanywhere.com/register

https://winmarimanzano.pythonanywhere.com/static/form-valid.js

Comment: - and I'm kinda sure that the Flask/flash() is at the error since my javascript file is running and sending data to my variable "data" on python. But when I'm for looping it, the flash(i) is not showing on the browser~

Comment: @WinmariManzano can you give the code like on github or somewhere else so that I can try it on my machine and heroku too.

Comment: @WinmariManzano did you check your web app error logs on PythonAnywhere as well?

Comment: @charchit here is the link https://github.com/DefinitelyNotAnAssassin/flask-chat

Comment: @cadeneuve yes I checked pythonanywhere's error log and it is not showing anything

Comment: Idk if this can help but I screen recorded how the same exact code acts on my local it's at https://streamable.com/ja62ua thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that using things such as flash() would just bring me more harm than using plain javascript and use empty small tags

```
const name = document.getElementById('username')
const password = document.getElementById('password')
const form = document.getElementById('mainform')
const second_password = document.getElementById("secure_pass")


const password_error = document.getElementById("password-error")
const second_error = document.getElementById("second-error")
const name_error = document.getElementById("name-error")

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  let messages = []
  if (name.value === '' || name.value == null) {
    messages.push('Filler')
    name_error.innerText = "Name is required."
  }
  else{
    name_error.innerText = ""
  }

  
  
  
  
  if (password.value != second_password.value || second_password.value != password.value){
    
    messages.push("Filler")
    second_error.innerText = "Password doesn't match"
  }
  else{
    second_error.innerText = ""
  }
  

  if (password.value.length >= 20) {
    messages.push('Filler')
    password_error.innerText = "Password should be less than 20 characters"
  }
  else if (password.value.length <= 8){
    messages.push('Filler')
    password_error.innerText = "Password should be atleast 8 characters"
  }
  else{
    password_error.innerText = ""
  }

  if (password.value === 'password') {
    messages.push('Password cannot be password \n')
  }

  if (messages.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault()    
  }
 
})
```

P.s don't mind the "filler" I just made it to add a counter to prevent submit.

```
let count = 0 
count += 1
```

Is simpler

Comment: so is your problem solved ? or Should I try pushing your code to heroku which you gave through github.

Comment: My problem is solved, I just used another method that does the same purpose. Tysm for trying to help~